# Moving a group of elements on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw a signal image as shown below at runtime on canvas.

sample code which I used to draw this signal is as below.

```
        Ellipse Ellipse1 = new Ellipse();
        Ellipse Ellipse2 = new Ellipse();
        Ellipse Ellipse3 = new Ellipse();
        Line lineV = new Line();
        Line lineH = new Line();

        lineV.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
        lineV.X1 = EndPosition.X;
        lineV.Y1 = EndPosition.Y;
        lineV.X2 = StartPosition.X;
        lineV.Y2 = EndPosition.Y;
        SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        redBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        lineV.StrokeThickness = 2;
        lineV.Stroke = redBrush;

       canvas1.Children.Add(lineV);

        lineH.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
        lineH.X1 = StartPosition.X;
        lineH.Y1 = EndPosition.Y;
        lineH.X2 = StartPosition.X;
        lineH.Y2 = StartPosition.Y;
        redBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        lineH.StrokeThickness = 2;
        lineH.Stroke = redBrush;

        canvas1.Children.Add(lineH);

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush1 = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush1.Color = Colors.Red; //FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
        Ellipse1.Fill = mySolidColorBrush1;
        Ellipse1.StrokeThickness = 2;
        Ellipse1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        Ellipse1.Width = 30;
        Ellipse1.Height = 30;
        Ellipse1.Margin = new Thickness(EndPosition.X, EndPosition.Y - 15, EndPosition.X + 50, EndPosition.Y + 50);

        canvas1.Children.Add(Ellipse1);

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush2 = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush2.Color = Colors.Green; //FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
        Ellipse2.Fill = mySolidColorBrush2;
        Ellipse2.StrokeThickness = 2;
        Ellipse2.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        Ellipse2.Width = 30;
        Ellipse2.Height = 30;
        Ellipse2.Margin = new Thickness(EndPosition.X + 30, EndPosition.Y - 15, EndPosition.X + 60, EndPosition.Y + 50);

        canvas1.Children.Add(Ellipse2);

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush3 = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush3.Color = Colors.Yellow; // FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
        Ellipse3.Fill = mySolidColorBrush3;
        Ellipse3.StrokeThickness = 2;
        Ellipse3.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        Ellipse3.Width = 30;
        Ellipse3.Height = 30;
        Ellipse3.Margin = new Thickness(EndPosition.X + 60, EndPosition.Y - 15, EndPosition.X + 150, EndPosition.Y + 50);

       canvas1.Children.Add(Ellipse3);
```

**Now I want the user to be able to interactively move this signal on the canvas on mouse move events.

How can I able to do this ?**

Iam using C# WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If want to implement a canvas to drag elements, a DragCanvas is your choice.

[Dragging Elements in a Canvas **from Josh Smith**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) and after [Dragging Elements in a Canvas **from igkutikov**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387977/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) that adapt Josh Smith code. There are articles with #mustread category.

With the dragCanvas you can implement a full functionality Dragging Element Canvas, and better adapt to your code. Happy coding!

Comment: Actually my question is "How to group these set of  elements and move the group as a single element "